# Why does this disk img mount only though a CDROM block device?

Tags: mount, ext4, dd, disk-image

I've created a disk image (not just a partition) of an SD card using `dd`. It contains one ext4 partition.

```
parallels@debian-gnu-linux-10:/media/psf/Irfan$ file -k old_armbian.img
old_armbian.img: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=62974604-6430-48bc-9f66-90d77651e3bf (extents) (large files) (huge files) (Lepton 3.x), scale 0-0, spot sensor temperature 0.000000, unit celsius, color scheme 0, calibration: offset 0.000000, slope 0.000000 (Lepton 2.x), scale 0-0, spot sensor temperature 0.000000, unit celsius, color scheme 0, calibration: offset 0.000000, slope 0.000000\012- data
```

I've been trying to mount this img on Debian via a loopback mount, but it refuses to detect and mount the ext4 that is contained in it.

The only way I was able to mount it was through a VM where I attached this img file to the CDROM device. After which I was able to mount it through the CDROM block device (`/dev/sr0`)

The issue:

```
$ sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop,ro ./old_armbian.img /mnt/PEND/
mount: /mnt/PEND: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
$ sudo mount ./old_armbian.img /mnt/PEND/
mount: /mnt/PEND: can't read superblock on /dev/loop0.
```

I've also tried doing `losetup`:

```
$ sudo losetup --partscan -f old_armbian.img
$ sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/loop0 /mnt/test
mount: /mnt/test: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Only this one worked:

```
$ sudo mount -t ext4 -o ro /dev/sr0 /mnt/PEND
```

What gives?

Comment: you're trying to mount /dev/loop0 at /mnt/PEND, but /mnt/PEND is already a mountpoint of /dev/sr0

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've made a new directory and also tried to mount there as well but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

With `-o loop` `mount` creates a loop device and tries to mount it, but the device doesn't contain an ext4 filesystem, it contains a partition table which is not mountable. You need to mount the partition on the image and `mount` can't do that, you need to create the loop device manually first with `--partscan` to tell kernel to probe the partition table and the mount the partition:

```
# losetup --partscan -f old_armbian.img

# mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/PEND
```

I'm not sure why this works with the virtual CD, it should have the same problem (it's possible the virtual CD is created with an offset and actually starts at the first partition or something like that).

Comment: I've tried this but `/dev/loop0p1` doesn't exist (updated my question to post screenshots)

Comment: Are you sure the image contains a partition? What does `blkid -p /dev/loop0` prints?

Comment: It doesn't print anything for `blkid -p /dev/loop0`. And yes, I'm certain this image contains an ext4 fs because `blkid -p /dev/sr0` gives me `/dev/sr0: UUID="62974604-6430-48bc-9f66-90d77651e3bf" VERSION="1.0" TYPE="ext4" USAGE="filesystem"`